# Screen Sensitivity of the retina display iPad (3rd generation). Is it better than before?

Tags: ipad, resolution, display, stylus

Does the new iPad support higher resolution tapping, or just more pixels for display. Stylii and the existing iPad feel like writing with a big marker on a big index card. Will the new iPad feel more like pen-and-paper **when using a stylus**?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but worth mentioning it. A while ago their was [a great project](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/531383637/jot-capacitive-touch-stylus?ref=live) on KickStarter, Jot. It was an ultra sensitive stylus for your iPad. And although it's not available anymore by KickStarter, you can still buy it on [their website](http://adonit.net/). It really worth the money!

Answer (score 5):

I practice, I can't tell any difference at all between the two models for most finger gestures on non-drawing apps.

Two things make this measurement hard - we don't get to see the raw pressure points and the unsmoothed and smoothed multitouch input. The end result of touch is highly processed which could easily hide changes in the detection grid / chip that does the processing / algorithms or tuning to make one iPad feel like the others.

The other is that our fingers cover the area we are selecting and for fine adjustments, you don't have to actually move your finger - just roll it to change the contact area of your deformed finger pad area that is either in direct contact or close proximity to the glass surface.

Once I learned to pivot and wiggle my fingers in place rather than try to slide it for fine adjustments - my precision (and feel of being able to control the precision) jumped immensely.

On the other hand - drawing with a stylus or deft and rapid strokes with a finger in a good drawing program makes the end feel on a retina iPad much better than before. I don't know if this is mental or real, but getting a finer line out of the same repeated gestures is incredible and makes the new hardware feel much more like pen or pencil and paper to me. I can't tell if it's the CPU/GPU or hardware or illusion, but the feel is quite real after a short adjustment period.

Comment: For what it's worth, I found I was far more accurate on my iPhone 3G than on both my 4 and 4S.

Comment: Thanks. What drawing program do you use? None of mine have updated to the higher resolution yet (nor would it matter as I don't have a new iPad). Also, is your stylus still a big finger-like pad, or do you have a stylus with a 'sharper' tip?

Comment: I'm using the cosmonaut and my finger exclusively. When I want a finer line, I increase the zoom factor. (programs are pre-release)

Answer (score 3):

Only if you file your fingers down to double precision ;)

But seriously, no, the actual capacative touch screen layer is unchanged, because the thing that is needs to interact with (your finger) remains unchanged.

To take a simple drawing application as an example, drawing a spiral will receive input from your fingers in the same way as on an iPad or iPad 2.  It takes the locations of your touch and tries to take an average of the "centre" of your touch point and this will produce the same results, although when translated into your drawing the enhanced resolution allows the touch algorithm to smooth out the centre area to a slightly more accurate level which may result in a more accurate looking drawing, but it's not due to any resolution changes in the touch sensitive layer, just a more accurate rendering of the existing input.

Comment: Your premise is flawed, as I don't interact with my finger, I interact with a stylus. Therefore, the higher resolution could be useful. You state that the capacitive touch screen layer is unchanged. Do you know this, or are you just guessing this because your finger is unchanged?

Comment: "could be useful", could being the operative word.  But the essense of locating your touch input is to calculate what it considers the center point of any touch contact, and providing an x/y co-ordinate to produce a pixel location.  that location has by it's nature to be at a "higher resolution" that previously, but it doesn't mean that it's actually any more accurate.  The premise isn't flawed in my view, it doesn't matter if you use a finger, a stylus, a sausage or a moon rock, it calculates the center point the same and smooths the input - the rest is just maths.

Comment: I should note that using a stylus does not necessarily improve the accuracy of any touch input, it's merely allows you to *see* where you are touching with more clarity, hence the illusion of greater fidelity.

Comment: But a stylus is a smaller point than a finger. Or a moon rock... You're answering a question about a precise input device with comments about sausages. I'm confused...

Comment: That was exactly my point (if you excuse the pun), it doesn't matter how large or small your pointing device, it's "centre" is the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a difference in screen touch sensitivity between the iPad Retina and the iPad 2. The former has a harder feel and is less sensitive to the touch. I still prefer using my iPhone 5 for everything even though the screen is smaller, the feel is so much better and way user friendly / faster on the touch.

As for stylus: the best for your iPad is Maglus by Applydea (love it!)
And for very fine writing and intricate stuff: Adonit Jot Pro.